# Loading multiple data-src (mp4+webm) in html5 video source

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I have a small custom video player within a wordpress project and it was working good so far, when I was only using one file format (mp4). But I have to also make use of webm now and I have problems to make the javascript code work.

```
<?php while( have_rows('v') ): the_row(); 
    // vars
    $mp4 = get_sub_field('id_mp4');
    $webm = get_sub_field('id_webm');
?>

<a class="play-video" data-src="<?php echo $mp4; ?>" data-webm="<?php echo $webm; ?>">VIDEO TITLE</a>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

And here is the target video section:

```
<video width="100%" height="auto" controls="true" class="video">
    <source src="<?php echo $mp4; ?>" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="<?php echo $webm; ?>" type="video/webm">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

And this is my JS code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.play-video', function() {
    $('#video-viewer video').attr('src', $(this).data('src'));
    $('#video-viewer video')[1].attr('src', $(this).data('webm')); // Not working
    $("#video-viewer video")[0].autoplay = true;

});
```

Can anyone help me to load the webm data src into the correct  section?

Comment: Your HTML appears ok. Verify that your sources are pointing to valid locations (no 404 errors). The browser will choose the one it supports and wants to use. You can use media queries as a way to test multiple sources in a single browser, so long as the browser supports all the video formats you are testing. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_source.asp

Comment: Thanks for your afford. Maybe I wasnt clear enough sorry, but my problem is that I cant load the content of data-webm="<?php echo $webm; ?> inside the second <video src> entry.

This is 100% wrong what I did here:   $('#video-viewer video')[1].attr('src', $(this).data('webm'));